# load cv::mat to faster rcnn blob

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently I am working with Faster RCNN using C++. I am trying to load cv Mat object (color image) to the `net_->blob_by_name("data")`. I follow the given instruction here https://github.com/YihangLou/FasterRCNN-Encapsulation-Cplusplus but the result is really bad:
[image: result image]

I didn't change anything from the original code. So I suspect loading data to blob might be the issue.

Code:

```
float im_info[3];
float data_buf[height*width*3];
float *boxes = NULL;
float *pred = NULL;
float *pred_per_class = NULL;
float *sorted_pred_cls = NULL;
int *keep = NULL;
const float* bbox_delt;
const float* rois;
const float* pred_cls;
int num;

for (int h = 0; h < cv_img.rows; ++h )
{
    for (int w = 0; w < cv_img.cols; ++w)
    {
        cv_new.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[0] = float(cv_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(w, h))[0])-float(102.9801);
        cv_new.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[1] = float(cv_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(w, h))[1])-float(115.9465);
        cv_new.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[2] = float(cv_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(w, h))[2])-float(122.7717);

    }
}

cv::resize(cv_new, cv_resized, cv::Size(width, height));
im_info[0] = cv_resized.rows;
im_info[1] = cv_resized.cols;
im_info[2] = img_scale;

for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h )
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w)
    {
        data_buf[(0*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[0]);
        data_buf[(1*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[1]);
        data_buf[(2*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[2]);
    }
}

net_->blob_by_name("data")->Reshape(1, 3, height, width);
net_->blob_by_name("data")->set_cpu_data(data_buf);
net_->blob_by_name("im_info")->set_cpu_data(im_info);
net_->ForwardFrom(0);
bbox_delt = net_->blob_by_name("bbox_pred")->cpu_data();
num = net_->blob_by_name("rois")->num();
```

Any advices ?

Comment: Hi this is the result I got.
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2s9Kc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please modify the code and check ...

```
cv::resize(cv_new, cv_resized, cv::Size(width, height));
im_info[0] = cv_resized.rows;
im_info[1] = cv_resized.cols;
im_info[2] = img_scale;

net_->blob_by_name("data")->Reshape(1, 3, height, width);
const shared_ptr<Blob<float> >& data_blob = net_->blob_by_name("data");
float* data_buf = data_blob->mutable_cpu_data();

for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h )
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w)
    {
        data_buf[(0*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f> cv::Point(w, h))[0]);
        data_buf[(1*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[1]);
        data_buf[(2*height+h)*width+w] = float(cv_resized.at<cv::Vec3f>(cv::Point(w, h))[2]);
    }
}

net_->Forward();
```